# Writing entries in an array of structures on file in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, structure

I'm writing a program in C and try to save an array of structures to a file.
My intention is to initialize an array of structs and save it to a file. Further I want to modify the entries of struct-entry 1, struct-entry 2, struct-entry 3 etc. But the entries are not written to the file. There even seems not to exist any array of structs.

I would appreciate any help, because I can't figure out, why the array is not written to  file.

Thank you
Threx

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct liste {
    unsigned int code;
    unsigned int activ;
    };
int main()
{
int z;

printf("Enter Index: "); /* Data should fill the z-th entry in array of structures */
scanf("%d",&z);

FILE *mrp;
struct liste bauteil[5]; /* Array with 5 structs for 5 different entries */

mrp = fopen("aaa.txt","w+b");

printf("Number of entry is: %d\n",z);
printf("Enter code: ");
scanf("%d",&bauteil[z].code);
bauteil[z].activ=77777; /* activ entry contains 77777 */

fseek(mrp, z * sizeof(struct liste), SEEK_SET);
fwrite(&bauteil[],sizeof(bauteil),1,mrp);

fclose(mrp);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the file already exist before your program starts? Or is your program supposed to create the file as you fill in the entries?

Comment: `fwrite(&bauteil[],sizeof(bauteil),1,mrp);` doesn't even compile. Is that a copying mistake? (It should be `fwrite(&bauteil[z],sizeof(bauteil),1,mrp);` to compile, but the actual size argument should be `sizeof bauteil[0]`).

Comment: @Scott: The file is supposed to exist before I fill it and the struct-entries have to be filled/modified later (for example with bauteil[2].code=123).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the fwrite parameters. To write the entire array you want to write the 5 structs, which are pointed at by `bauteil`. Try `fwrite(bauteil,sizeof(struct liste),5,mrp);`  Currently the write is too short, since sizeof(bauteil) wont return the size of the entire array.

Comment: I modified fwrite. Your suggestion seemed necessary and is a move in the right direction, but still I don't get access to the array. Instead the arry will be filled with random values and I can not enter them whatsoever...

Comment: Expect most of the output to currently be random values since most entries are never written.  when you look at the file, don't expect to see the numbers in ascii format, since you are writing them as their binary representation.

Comment: I try read them not as a .txt-file directly. Instead I use printf. This works until after 6 entry the txt-file is spoiled beyond recovery. That is the firt 5 entries can be modified and read just fine... weird!

Answer (score 0):

to

```
mrp = fopen("aaa.txt","r+b");
fwrite(&bauteil[z],sizeof(struct liste),1,mrp);
```

Comment: Doesn't sizeof(struct liste) overwrites the hole struct array? If this happens, all entries exept the very last would be ereased, don't they? My test showed, this is the case...

Comment: @Threx I think that we can rewrite the record of only one.